# How to call function method inside ajax success function?

Tags: javascript

How to call pagePresets.setFilter() inside `$.ajax(){success}` method?

`self.setFilter.call('network', data.networks);` returns

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)

when `self.setFilter('network', data.networks);`

> Uncaught TypeError: self.setFilter is not a function(…)

Code:

```
function pagePresets() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.isLoading = function () {
        return this.loading;
    };
    this.setLoading = function (state) {
        this.loading = state;
        return;
    };
    /** this function loads saved filters */
    this._loadFilters = function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'data.json',
            success: function (data) {
                //HOW TO CALL setFilter? this solution is not working
                pagePresets.prototype.setFilter.call('network', data.networks);
            }
        });
    };
}

pagePresets.prototype.setFilter = function (target, value) {
 console.info(target + ' ' + value );
}
```

Comment: Try `new pagePresets().setFilter('network', data.networks);`

If you have/need only a single pagePresets instance, use an object instead.

Comment: *this solution is not working* - add some details for `pagePresets.prototype.setFilter.call(` ... errors ?

Answer (score 1):

The `call` function takes as first argument a "context object". Take a deeper look at the call function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

In the ajax callback function `this` or `self` doesn't refere to your class object anymore. And `pagePresets` is a function class with no static properties. So you need to get the object instance.

You need to specify which instance you want to call your prototype function with. I usualy declare a private property in my "class" wich holds a reference to the object for such scenarios where the context changes.

```
function pagePresets() {
    //create a local variable here
    var localInstance = this;

    this.loading = true;
    this.isLoading = function () {
        return this.loading;
    };
    this.setLoading = function (state) {
        this.loading = state;
        return;
    };
    /** this function loads saved filters */
    this._loadFilters = function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            url: 'data.json',
            success: function (data) {
                //Use the variable here to specify the correct context.
                //the functions arguments need to be an array for the call function
                pagePresets.setFilter.call(localInstance, [ 'network', data.networks ]);
            }
        });
    };
}

pagePresets.prototype.setFilter = function (target, value) {
    console.info(target + ' ' + value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to invoke that in the another function like this

```
function success() {
    pagePresets.prototype.setFilter.call('network', data.networks);
}

function error() {
    alert("error");
}


function searchEntity(id,userName, family) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/mvc-test/rest/user/searchAll?pageNumber=1&pageSize=2&&orderBy=userName asc",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getMetaContentByName('_csrf')},
        data : JSON.stringify({
            "id":id,
            "userName" : userName,
            "familyName" : family
        }),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : success,
        error : error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass the parent context into the success method or delegate.

In the code below, `onAjaxResponseReceived` function is called with with the reference to the parent (class) context `self` from which other methods `func1` and `func2` can be accessed.

```js
class TestClass{
    constructor(searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }

    bind() {
        self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: self.searchUrl,
            type:"POST",
            data: data,
            success: function (responseData) {
                self.onAjaxResponseReceived(self, responseData);
            }
       });
    }

    onAjaxResponseReceived(self, data) {
        self.func1(data);
        self.func2(data);
    }

    func1(data) {
        console.log('func 1');
    }

    func2(data) {
        console.log('func 2');
    }

}
```